# Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen Grippe und echter Grippe?

Tags: meaning, difference

Ich habe beide *die Grippe* und *die echte Grippe* als Namen für die Influenza gehört. Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen *die Grippe* und *die echte Grippe*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Zu [***„Grippe“***](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=grippe&view=1) findet sich im etymologischen Wörterbuch nach Pfeifer folgender Eintrag:

> **Grippe** f. ‘fieberhafte Erkältungskrankheit, epidemisch auftretende Viruserkrankung’, Übernahme (Ende 18. Jh., etwa zur selben Zeit wie *Influenza*, s. d.) von gleichbed. frz. *grippe*. Dieses ist wahrscheinlich Verbalsubstantiv zu frz. *gripper* ‘ergreifen, fassen, haschen’, das (vgl. *être grippé* ‘erfaßt werden’) das plötzliche Auftreten dieser Krankheit zu bezeichnen sucht.

Der Begriff stammt also aus einer Zeit, in der man über Viren, die Erkältungskrankheiten auslösen, noch nichts wusste. So erklärt sich, weshalb man bis heute zu jeder rasch auftretenden und mit Fieber einhergehenden Erkältung immer noch *„Grippe“* sagt. Dies schließt auch die im heutigen Sprachgebrauch nur noch als *„Influenza“* benannte, umgangssprachlich *„echte Grippe“* ein, die durch [Influenzaviren](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Influenzavirus) ausgelöst wird.

Im medizinischen Gebrauch findet sich noch der Ausdruck *„grippaler Infekt“* für Erkältungskrankheiten, die durch eine Reihe anderer Viren hervorgerufen werden können.

Nicht mit Fieber einhergehende Erkältungen sind auch umgangssprachlich keine *„Grippe“,* sondern werden meist nach ihren Symptomen bezeichnet: *Husten*, *Schnupfen*.

Sonderformen einer *Grippe* sind z. B. auch die umgangssprachliche *Sommergrippe* und eine *Darmgrippe*.

Answer (score 14):

In der Alltagssprache wird das Wort „Grippe“ oft verwendet, um alle Arten von [grippalen Infekten](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erk%C3%A4ltung) zu beschreiben. Oft wird eine einfache, kurzfristige Erkältung als „eine Grippe“ beschrieben.

Die „echte Grippe“ hingegen ist die [Influenza](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grippe), die in der Regel ein deutlich schwerwiegenderes Krankheitsbild hat.

Answer (score 1):

Wer sagt "ich leide an der echten Grippe" will einer Nachfrage, ob er die Grippe vielleicht mit einer Erkältung verwechselt, was in nachlässigen Kreisen oft vorkommt, zuvorkommen.

Wer sagt "Ich leide an einer Grippe" lässt dies offen, so dass man überlegen kann, ob diese Person sich da eine Nachlässigkeit leistet, bzw. ob die Umstände dafür oder dagegen sprechen, dass eine Erkältung gemeint ist (gleichzeitige Erwähnung von Krankenhaus, Erbschaft einerseits, oder der Patient schneuzt sich den Kopf leer, schaut aber Fern und ist guter Stimmung).